# Private helper method to capture wildcard type for generic methods

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, bounded-wildcard, helpermethods

The following code does not compile in Eclipse. It says "The method putHelper(List,int,E) in the type Abc is not applicable for the arguments (List <.capture#8-of extends E>",int,E)"

```
private <E> void putHelper(List<E> list, int i, E value) {
    list.set(i, value);
}

public <E> void put(List<? extends E> list, int toPos, E value) {
    // list.set(toPos,value);
    putHelper(list, toPos, value);
}
```

I don't understand why it is so?
Because the code below works fine.

```
  public <E> void put(List<? extends E> list,int fromPos, int toPos) {
  putHelper(list,fromPos,toPos);
  }

  private <E> void putHelper(List<E> list,int i, int j) {
  list.set(j,list.get(i));
  }
```

And I understand that here the helper method is able to capture the wildcard type, but why not in the earlier code?

EDIT: In the third case, if I change type parameter in the put method to List<.? super E> and when I try to call the put() method from another method which takes a list, Eclipse doesn't compile it. It says, "The method put(List<.? super E>,int,E) in the type Abc is not applicable for the arguments (List <.capture#6-of extends E>",int,E)"

```
public static <E> void insertAndProcess(List<? extends E> list) {

// Iterate through the list for some range of values i to j

    E value = list.get(i);

//Process the element and put it back at some index

    put(list, i+1, value);

//Repeat the same for few more elements
}

private static <E> void putHelper(List<E> list, int i, E value) {
    list.set(i, value);
}

public static <E> void put(List<? super E> list, int toPos, E value) {
    putHelper(list, toPos, value);
}
```

Here, how can insertAndProcess() call put() method and use it in its implementation, while the user can still be able to call both these methods with say ArrayList<.Integer>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the *Get and Put Principle* also known by the acronym *PECS* which stands of Producer Extends, Consumer Super.

This is explained in this SO question: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

But basically:

```
public <E> void put(List<? extends E> list, int toPos, E value) {
   // list.set(toPos,value);
   putHelper(list, toPos, value);
}
```

`<? extends E>` can't be used here because the `List` is being used as a consumer (it is taking elements) so it should use `super` instead of `extends`.

```
public <E> void put(List<? super E> list, int toPos, E value) {
   // list.set(toPos,value);
   putHelper(list, toPos, value);
}
```

**EDIT**

In your 2nd case, `List` is acting as a *producer* because it is producing elements via the call to `get()` so you can use `extends`.

However, in your 3rd example, you are both getting and putting into the same list so I don't think you can use wildcards at all.

This compiles:

```
public static <E> void insertAndProcess(List<E> list) {

    // Iterate through the list for some range of values i to j
    E value = list.get(i);

    // Process the element and put it back at some index
    putHelper(list, i+1, value);

    // Repeat the same for few more elements
}
```

Note that since we don't need to use any wildcards anyway because we are getting and setting from the same list so the type `E` must be the same no matter what it is.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. In the second case, where the code works, is the List consumer or producer? I have edited the question and added another case, please help with the third case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Well, I wanted to restrict the calls to the method insertAndProcess() by passing lists of type, say Number, only because it uses some specific implementation for that type, so I needed to use <? extends E>. I guess, I'd have to restrict that in the class itself now.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are sometimes a bit difficult. Try to analyze it step by step.

Imagine - in your first example (that doesn't compile) - you call the `put` method with the type variable `E` replaced by `Number`. As you are constraining the input parameter `list` with `List<? extends E>` it could be a `List<Integer>` for example. The parameter `value` is of type `E` (remember: `E` is `Number`), so it could be a `Double` for example. And this must not be allowed because you would try to add a `Double` into a `List<Integer>`.

In the second example you only have a constraint on the input parameter `list`. No other parameter is dependent on `E`. Setting and getting on a list will always work because the elements in question must be of the same type.

A solution:

Always remind the acronym *PECS*. See [Wildcard (Java)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_%28Java%29). That means you should declare the `put` method as following (in your first example):

```
public <E> void put(List<? super E> list, int toPos, E value) {
    putHelper(list, toPos, value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The clear explanation helped a lot. I had read about PECS, but I declared put(List<? extends E>) so that it could be used with insertAndProcess(), please see the EDITED question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @shujin When _producing_ and _consuming_ you cannot declare _extends_ nor _super_. So you must stick to `List<E>`.

Answer (score 0):

`List<E>` will accept only E class objects where as `List<? extends E>` can accept any sub-class of E.

When you say a method can accept only `List<E>` passing `List<? extends E>` will confuse the compiler because it does not know which type of Object your list will actually contain.

Note that in java, this is illegal:

```
List<E> list = new ArrayList<? extends E>();
```

E.g. `List<Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

In the second example, your list expects any sub-class of E and what your passing is list of E objects so its allowed.
E.g. `List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`